# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" when using curl in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, curl

I installed curl by using brew: `brew install curl` and has added `/usr/local/Cellar` to the header searching path of my xcode project.

But **"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"** error occurs when building the project.

Is it a problem related my OSX version (10.9)? Any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely that you have installed the 32-bit library, and are using the compiler in 64-bit mode. Without seeing exactly what errors you are getting and what the code looks like, that's one of the better guesses you'll get, I expect.